# How do I know where I need to be to work on my Heart's Desire?

Tags: fallen-london

I am working on my Heart's Desire, and I keep having to change locations, but I don't really get much information always about where I need to be. Is there a way to know where I need to be to work on my Heart's Desire, or is it just something I have to figure out by systematically visiting locations?

Comment: If you look at your character (the "Myself" tab) and open up the *Ambition* section in the *Qualities* area, you'll get a summary of where you've been and what you've learned, in the form of several different Qualities. Does one of those help? (I can't confirm it with my character, because I'm halfway through a location with my Ambition.)

Answer (score 1):

Alas, there's no good way to figure out where your Ambition is going to take you next. Even the text of the last completed storylet isn't necessarily useful: sometimes it will give you a location (such as the Shuttered Palace), and sometimes it will give you an incredibly vague hint (such as a name), that won't guide your next action at all.

You have three options:

1. Look at the Ambition qualities you have picked up (on the "Myself" tab). If you're lucky, the last one's description will give you a hint on where to go next.
2. Spoil yourself silly by reading the wiki
3. Randomly wander around until you find the next location for your ambition. If you can't see it, then it must be somewhere you haven't unlocked yet.